# Accessing aggregate result map

Tags: apex, map

I have the following code;

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, TotalVisitbyCurrentOwner__c, OwnerSince__c, Owner.Id FROM Account WHERE AccountCountry__c = 'ID' AND (TypeOfCompany__c = 'Developer' OR TypeOfCompany__c = 'Bank') AND Owner.IsActive = true ];
        system.debug('total account = ' + accs);

        Map<Id, Account> accIds = new Map<Id, Account>();
        accIds.putAll(accs);

Map<Id, AggregateResult> meetingActivities = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT MAX(CompletedDate__c) datemax, WhatId Id FROM Task WHERE (Type__c = 'Meeting' OR Type__c = 'meeting')  AND Status = 'Completed' AND CallResult__c = 'Successful' AND  WhatId IN: accIds.keySet() GROUP BY WhatId]);

        system.debug('total of meeting activities = ' + meetingActivities);

for(Account temp : accs){

            if(meetingActivities.keySet().contains(temp.Id)){ 
                temp.TotalVisitbyCurrentOwner__c += 1;
                temp.DateofLastVisit__c = Date.valueof(meetingActivities.get(temp.Id);
            }
        }
        
        update accs;
```

inside for loop, I need to populate field DateofLastVisit__c from the aggregate result "datemax" that corresponds to the id of the Account in the loop. how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `get` method as you would on `SObject`.

```
AggregateResult aggregateRecord = aggregates.get(...);
Date aggregateValue = (Date)aggregateRecord.get('dateMax');
```

If you hadn't given the field an alias, it would instead be `.get('expr0')`.

Comment: Sorry but I still dont follow, the aggregate result is in the map object, if I put ```meetingActivities.get(temp.Id)``` then I get ```AggregateResult:{datemax=Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 GMT 2019, Id=0016E000014kNP7QAM}``` , I need to access only the datemax

Comment: Yes exactly...so you call `.get('dateMax')` on that `AggregateResult`. `meetingActivities.get(temp.Id).get('dateMax')`